# Creating matrix with reading from a file

Tags: database, matlab, matrix

I wanted to write a code to do this command for me but I have a problem with defining iterative part:
My requirement: I have 101 files which are ended with a number that can be used as a numerator like file_01 to file_101. I want to have "for loop" to do this: removing 3 columns from each file and adding 3 columns with different arrays to those files. The arrays should be read from a specific excel file.
could you please help me

```
 clear all
 clc
 close all

 files = dir('*.txt');
 for i=1:length(files)
     eval(['load ' files(i).name ' -ascii']);
 end
para = xlsread('parameters.xlsx');
```

and for other part

```
T = size(x1);

j = T(:,1); 

A = zeros(j,1);
for i =0:length(N)
    % Deleting the first column
    x1(:,1)=[];
    newcol = zeros(j,1);
    x1 = [newcol x1];
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data = xlsread('parameters.xlsx');
files = dir('*.txt');
for i = 1:length(files)
    A = load(files(i).name);        % load data from txt
    A(1:3,:) = [];                  % remove first 3 columns
    A = [A data(1:3,:)];            % add 3 column from excel data
    dlmwrite(files(i).name,A);      % re-write current file
end
```

Remember that number of rows from **excel** and **txt** files should be the same

Comment: Thanks but the problem is this excel file saved parameters for each time step which is 100-time steps but each time step (I mean txt files) is for 1600 nodes. so I want to read them from excel file copy them for 1600 times in text files columns.

Comment: I have 100 files for different time steps. each of which has 1000 rows that imply a different spatial location. I have also another file that keeps parameters for each time step so it has 100 rows. I want to remove and add 3 new free columns. These columns should be filled by reading from the parameter. Thus we should copy each row of parameter in 1000 rows because in one step we have just one row of parameter that is repeated for 1000 points